# How do you create a 404 Error route in Flask (Python) to connect to my 404.html page?

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I followed along with a video and the following is what my code looks like in my Flask

I have a HTML page in my templates as well. Whenver I put a dummy link it just says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2023 01:01:51] "GET /About/l HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This is what my flask looks like

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from authorize import role_required
from models import *
import hashlib


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template("404.html"), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This works for me. Please share a [mcve].